# jquery datepicker, no respond even tho another jsp with shared import works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function for a jquery inplug datepicker. I've got two jsp pages, both in the same folder. And a base.jsp which gives every jsp page the same values/imports. The below function resides in base.

```
 $(function() {
      $( "#datepickerFrom" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
 });
```

my datepicker `<input type="text" id="datepickerFrom">`

It works in one of my jsp pages, but not the other? What could possible cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {        
      $( "#datepickerFrom" ).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
 });
```

Comment: If you are in any ajax call then please add the jquery.min library in that page also.

Comment: I tried loading everything in the base into the page that doesen't work but no luck. Both pages uses bootstrap, but maybe that interferes with it.

Comment: I faced these kind of problem a lot of time and get ride from it via this way, But in your page why this not works i am not sure. 

I have no any idea.